# Slides from Word outline don't match the slide Master

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-powerpoint, format, master, outline

I am working in Office 365 importing slides to PowerPoint from an outline in Word.  I have the slide master set up with the font sizes, types, and colors I want, as well as the bullet types.  When I import the slides, however, none of the slide master format appears and even when I right click on thumbnails and choose the slide format or choose my master theme and apply it to all slides.

Is there an option somewhere for formatting of slides imported from an outline?

Is there a work-around so I can change the formatting after the fact?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This need doesn't seem feasible.

When you import slides to PowerPoint from an outline in Word, slides will be rendered in a style that has been set in word.

You can modify their fonts and other settings in the word outline instead of master slides.

Comment: Thank you.  I sort of figured that out but it still only partly matches.  No matter what font I have in the outline the slides have times new roman.  It really makes things difficult to do all my formatting in Word, when I would like to just have the outline be normal text.